# DataTables TableTools

Tags: jquery, css, tabletools

[DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) is up and running on my site.  I can't seem to get the tableTools css to work.  In particular, I want the `copy_csv_pdf_print.swf` to load. I am able to render the table with only some of the styling.

The `copyCSVExcelPDFPrint` links should render as buttons in the top left (i.e. http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) but instead they render as links.

I loaded the necessary css and javascript files, including the css files for tableTools; and then the jQuery code below.  In my php file, I target the table with id `demo`.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
    $('#demo').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip<"clear spacer">T'
    } );
} );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with integrating within WordPress, but more so the actual JS tool itself (regardless if WP or not)?

Answer (score 1):

maybe u have to bind media folder structure. default swf file binding is below. you have to change to yours.

```
"sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
```